# OCaml count the negatives

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm really stuck on how to go about this I am asked to count the number of negatives within the list, I would have submitted the assignment with:

```
let nneg = [4; 9; -5; 0; -5; 1];;
List.filter nneg (fun -> (-))
List.filter nneg (fun x -> x < 0)
```

but it's not an `int list -> int` but instead an `int list`

so I started this but I can't figure it out for the life of me how to pattern match it:

```
   let rec rev nneg = 
     match nneg with 
     | [] -> 0 
     | head::tail -> (filter tail < 0) head;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to filter the list. You want to **fold** it to an int. Also the call has wrong arguments.

```
# List.filter;;
- : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
```

So filter is a function that takes a function that returns bool and a list. Filter returns filtered list. Example usage of filter:

```
# List.filter (fun x -> x > 0) [1;2;3;-3];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

Since this is an assignment I'll just give you a hint. Have a look at fold function [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html). Obviously, you can solve it by filtering all elements greater or equal 0 and then counting them, but that requires two iterations.